# Does the serie converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine if the serie converges or diverges $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)^{n}$

I tried the divergence theorem, the nth root test and the integral test. Unfortunately, I got no answer and don't know what to do. Is there even an analytic answer?

Comment: Note that as $n$ increases, $(1-\frac{\operatorname{ln}n}{n})^n$ approaches $e^{-\operatorname{ln}n}=n^{-1}=\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\displaystyle a_n:=\left(1-\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^n$ and $b_n:=\dfrac1n$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(1-\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^n \overset{\star}{=} 1 > 0$$
therefore, by the [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), either both series converge or both series diverge.

But, of course, $\displaystyle\sum b_n$ diverges, so $\displaystyle\sum a_n$ diverges.

---

$(\star)$ Notice that $\displaystyle \ln(1-x) = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k} = -x+O(x^2)$. Therefore, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln\left(n\left(1-\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^n\right) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln n + n\ln\left(1-\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln n + n\left(-\frac{\ln n}{n}+O\left(\frac{\ln^2 n}{n^2}\right)\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} O\left(\frac{\ln^2 n}{n}\right)\\
&= 0
\end{aligned}$$